# Random widths of divs on single line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a group of divs, that are all on one line, that need to be random widths but the total of all the divs needs to be equal to the width of the containing div.

I was thinking of using percentages for the widths. How would I go about randomly generating those width percentages on page load?

Obviously, I need to use javascript to do this. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. I can't use jquery for this, has to be plain old javascript.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you may have.

my divs look like this:

```
<div class="progWrap">
                    <div class="adhSec"></div>
                    <div class="combSec"></div>
                    <div class="dosSec"></div>
                    <div class="guidSec"></div>
                    <div class="safSec"></div>
                    <div class="othSec"></div>
                </div>
```

the final effect I am going for is like so:

[image: Divs in a row]

Comment: The amount of divs is known in advance? Or should it work with an arbitrary number of elements? there's a minimum width? Have you tried something?

Comment: Where's your code? And what have you tried?

Comment: so far I haven't tried anything, was just looking for a nod in the right direction. As for the number of div's there are 6 div's in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flex-box's flex-grow property as show below, and use JS to generate a random number for the flex-grow value on each div. You can easily add divs to the code to get as many as you need. I just did it with four.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Sareliz126/pen/KrVpZr

Reference on flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>flex grow random</title>
    <style>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grow {
  height: 60px;
}


#first {
  background-color: pink;
}

#second {
  background-color: blue;

}

#third {
  background-color: green;

}

#fourth {
  background-color: yellow;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="grow" id="first"></div>
  <div class="grow" id="second"></div>
  <div class="grow" id="third"></div>
  <div class="grow" id="fourth"></div>
</div>


<script>
  const randomize = () => {

    document.getElementById('first').style.flexGrow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById('second').style.flexGrow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById('third').style.flexGrow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById('fourth').style.flexGrow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  };

  window.onload=randomize;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. With a couple of little modifications to suit my needs it was perfect. Thank you @SarahElizabethWaldie

Comment: You're welcome! Please check out the codepen for a more concise version of the function too, looping like @thijs-kramer mentioned.

Comment: @M_Griffiths, if you add a starting flex-grow value to the .grow class and set a transition, you get a nice effect:

.grow {
  height: 60px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

Comment: Thank you, again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nod in the right direction:

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align the divs in their parent. 
Then write some javascript that does the following:

1. Select all divs inside `.progWrap` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. Loop over these divs, and do the following for each div:

   - Generate a random width (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
   - Apply the random width to the div (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. It generates 6 integers you can use for the width properties. There is a limit to the maximum value that can be generated, currently set at 20 although the last div can get a higher value depending on the outcome for the first 5 divs.

In case you want to set a minimum value for the width, you can easily include a condition inside the while loop.

```js
const divs = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 21); // Random number
const max = 100; // Maximum value for width
const numberOfDivs = 6;
const el = []; // Store width values
let start = 0; // Makes while loop stop when more than 100
let actual = 0; // Stores sum of widths while < 100
let i = 0; // Counting number of divs added to el
while (start < max && i < numberOfDivs) {
  const x = divs();
  el.push(x);
  start += x;
  i++;
  if (start < max) actual += x;
}
const arLength = el.length;
const lastValue = el[5];
el.splice(arLength - 1, 1); // Remove last element
el.push(max - actual + lastValue); // Add element with remaining width
console.log(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any indication which part of the problem you're struggling with.

Here's a very crude implementation of what you're describing:

```js
const a = Math.random();
const b = Math.random();
const c = Math.random();
const sum = a + b + c;

document.write(`
  <div style="background:#f00;float:left;height:50px;width:${a/sum*100}%"></div>
  <div style="background:#0f0;float:left;height:50px;width:${b/sum*100}%"></div>
  <div style="background:#00f;float:left;height:50px;width:${c/sum*100}%"></div>
`);
```

Answer (score -4):

You don't have to use JavaScript or jQuery if it's on page refresh.

PHP can be run once.

As such you could do :

```
// Set a full width parent div.

<div id="parent" style="width: 100%;"> 
<?php

$width_max = 100;
$number_of_divs = 6;
$div_widths = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_divs; $i++){
$random_width = rand(0, $width_max);
$width_max -= $random_width;
array_push($div_widths, $random_with);
    }

for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfDivs; $i++){ ?>
<div style="width:<?php echo $div_width[$i];?>"></div>
   <?php }
?>

</div>
```

However, if for whatever reason you would prefer, you can also do this in JavaScript, although there is no need to rely on this instead as JavaScript can be turned off.

```
<script>



window.onload = function(){
    generateDivs();
    }

function generateDivs(){

var width_max = 100; 
var number_of_divs = 6;
var div_widths = new Array();
var parent_div = document.getElementById("parent");

for(var i = 0; i < number_of_divs; i++){
var random_width = Math.floor((Math.random() * width_max) + 1);
width_max -= random_width;
div_widths.push(random_width);
}

for(var i = 0; i < number_of_divs; i++){
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
parent_div.appendChild(newDiv);
newDiv.style.width = div_widths[i];
}

}
</script>
```

Note in the JavaScript example, you'll still have to include an HTML Div with width 100% and id="parent".

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because you are suggesting to use PHP to solve the problem...

Comment: @ThijsKramer Which is unfortunate because the answer is correct, both in that PHP would do, and that JavaScript can be turned off.